# Load Windows Registry of Docker container from file on startup of Windows Docker Container

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, dockerfile, containers

I am very new to Docker, so perhaps I am just missing something simple, but I have not been able to figure out a way to accomplish this task.

I have a Dockerfile that looks like this:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:10.0.17763.3046-amd64

RUN mkdir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Austin Lane Technologies"
RUN mkdir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Austin Lane Technologies\ALMobile Suite"

WORKDIR "C:/Program Files (x86)/Austin Lane Technologies/ALMobile Suite/"
COPY ./BaseInstall/ProgramFiles/ .

WORKDIR "C:/Program Files (x86)/Austin Lane Technologies/ALMobile Suite/bin"

RUN "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/installutil.exe" /Logfile=SystemSvc.install.log SystemSvc.exe
RUN "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/installutil.exe" /Logfile=DataInterfaceSvc.install.log DataInterfaceSvc.exe
RUN "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/installutil.exe" /Logfile=DataSyncSvc.install.log DataSyncSvc.exe
RUN "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/installutil.exe" /Logfile=AUServerSvc.install.log AUServerSvc.exe
RUN "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/installutil.exe" /Logfile=ADExplorerSvc.install.log ADExplorerSvc.exe

This scripts builds the image:
docker build -t almobile:latest .

I then launch an Admin Powershell Window and do the following:
.\runalmobile_test.ps1, which contains:
docker run --user ContainerAdministrator --name master -v "C:\ALMobileSuiteProgramFiles\Master\ProgramFiles:C:\Program Files (x86)\Austin Lane Technologies\ALMobile Suite" -p 2089:2089 -p 2090:2090 -p 2091:2091 -p 2093:2093 -it almobile cmd.exe

The registry file I want to load resides in the C:\ALMobileSuiteProgramFiles\Master\ProgramFiles directory.

I am able to load the registry of the container with the contents of this file if I manually enter the regedit command from an Admin Powershell window, but what I want to do is to have the regedit import command automatically issued when the container starts. So, once the cmd.exe shell launches, I am in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Austin Lane technologies\ALMobile Suite\bin folder. If I manually issue the following command, all works:
regedit /i /s ..\ALMobile.reg

What is the best practice/way for me to automatically import this registry file at time of container startup? Is there a way to run the regedit command from the Dockerfile, or does this need to be executed from some alternate script?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run the Registry file during the `docker build` step, not the `docker run` step. And use `reg import` instead of `regedit`. So in your Dockerfile, you would have something like this, assuming you are using Powershell:

```
COPY ALMobile.reg .
RUN Invoke-Command {reg import ALMobile.reg}
```